# mathtools part of TeX Live 2012 but not accessible?

Tags: mathtools

I'm having problems being able to use the `mathtools` package.  It seems to be installed on my system after I installed the complete TeX Live 2012 system.

If I run the GUI on my Ubuntu installation thus: `tlmgr -gui` I can see that the `mathtools` package is said to be installed.  But I can't use it in my Texmaker.

I get an error when I try to "quick build" in my Texmaker.  At the beginning of the file I have this line: "\userpackage{mathtools}"  I'm pasting the part showing the error from the log file:

Any ideas?

Ps: Please excuse me, I'm new to this community and just learning how to use this web.  If I'm not doing things correctly, please don't judge me too hard.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mathtools.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.7 \savesymbol
{iint}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
933 strings out of 495061
9434 string characters out of 1182620
58609 words of memory out of 3000000
4164 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+50000
4702 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
28 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
24i,0n,19p,199b,38s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Can you please tell us the exact error that you get? Otherwise it is difficult to answer your questions as a lot of guessing is involved

Comment: Yes, I can.  To begin with I'm using this statement "\usepackage{mathtools}", at the start of the tex file that I'm trying to compile when I get this error: [link](https://gist.github.com/3882745)

Comment: The message says `mathtools.sty` can't be found; but you said you have installed a complete TeX Live2012 distribution. Perhaps you had another distribution before and you haven't updated the path to the new installation? Can you please process the following simple test document `\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}` and upload elsewhere (providing here a link) the resulting `.log` file?

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo Medina.  First, let me tell you that before I installed TeX Live 2012 I didn't have any other distribution.  I did this on a fresh new Ubuntu 12.04 setup.

I did the test you asked me to do.  Here is the resulting log file:

[link](https://gist.github.com/3882877)

Comment: @user19851 As I suspected, your system is using a preexisting distribution. The first line of the `.log` file says `(TeX Live 2009/Debian)`, so you have another installation that is being used instead of the 2012 distribution you installed. The best thing to do would be to remove this old installation and then update the path so your editor will use the TeX Live2012 one.

Comment: This is strange! Is it possible that the Texmaker installation forced me to install TeX Live 2009 without me knowing it !? That's just not right! How can I remove it completely? I have already removed everything I see marked TeX Live 2009 from the "Ubuntu Software Center" but when I run your test I still get the same info in the log file: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)" I don't know how to get rid of this old distribution!

Comment: @user19851 the old installation is under `/usr/share/` you can manually delete the directories there associated to TeX Live2009. More important yet is to update the path so that TeX Live2012 is used; I am not familiar with TeXmaker, but you can  try copying the following lines in the `.profile` file: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH 
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH`, restart your session and try again with the example.

Comment: @user19851 check under `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/` to see the correct last directory for the first line.